# Data for current user will not display without a refresh, MERN stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, mern

Good afternoon/morning!

I have been working on this for a few days and can't seem to figure this one out. It worked perfect running locally using json server and localhost. Now that its deployed to heroku I get this problem.

**PROBLEM**: If I log in a user, it won't display anything unless I refresh. If I had a different user logged in recently, it will display their data unless I hit refresh. This is just for testing, I am doing all of this from my computer.

**WHAT IVE TRIED** Just about everything I can think of. Looking at the network console to see the order of when things are fetched, I am pretty sure I see the problem.

When I first log in I get this order  in the network tab

**login**

**tokenIsValid**

**get**

**users**

when I refresh I get

**profile**

**(static chunks for heroku)**

**react devtools backend**

**tokenIsValid**

**get**

**users**

I am pretty new at this, but seeing the get request for users come after the get request for my users data is causing this issue. When I refresh, It does't matter the order because I am still logged in. That's my logic anyway.

So here is my code for the relative components

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./Components/Profile";
import Main from "./Components/Main";
import UserContext from "./Components/UserContext";
import SearchResults from "./Components/SearchResults";

function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState({
    token: null,
    user: null,
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route path="/search" component={SearchResults} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.jsx

```
... the code for my get request

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      try {
        const loginUser = { email, password };
        const loginRes = await axios.post("/users/login", loginUser, authToken);
        setUserData({
          token: loginRes.data.token,
          user: loginRes.data,
        });
        console.log(loginRes.data.token)
        localStorage.setItem("auth-token", loginRes.data.token);
        history.push("/profile");
      } catch (err) {
        err.response.data.msg && setError(err.response.data.msg);
      }
    };
```

ShowRecords.jsx

```
....

//set state for records and userData

 const [newRecords, newRecordData] = React.useState([]);

 const { setUserData } = React.useContext(UserContext);

....

//fetch record data

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get("record/get", authToken);
    newRecordData(result.data);
    console.log(result.data)
  };

  // see if user is logged in already, if not set a token and userData

  const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
    if (token === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "");
      token = null;
    }
    const tokenRes = await axios.post("/users/tokenIsValid", null, {
      headers: { "x-auth-token": token },
    });
    if (tokenRes.data) {
      const userRes = await axios.get("/users", {
        headers: { "x-auth-token": token },
      });
      setUserData({
        token: userRes.data,
        user: userRes.data,
      });
    }
  };


  React.useEffect(() => {
    checkLoggedIn()
    fetchData();
    

    console.log("data");
  }, []);

....
```

edit: here is my backend

UserRoute.js

```
... relavent routes 
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // validate
    if (!email || !password)
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Wait... some fields are empty!" });

    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!user)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "No account with this email has been registered." });

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials." });

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    res.json({
      token,
      user: {
        id: user._id,
        displayName: user.displayName,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});

router.post("/tokenIsValid", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.json(false);

    const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    if (!verified) return res.json(false);

    const user = await User.findById(verified.id);
    if (!user) return res.json(false);

    return res.json(true);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});

router.get("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user);
  res.json({
    displayName: user.displayName,
    id: user._id,
  });
});

...
```

RecordRoute.js

```
... all other routes here aren't related and work fine

//get records

router.get("/get", auth, async(req,res) =>{
  const records = await Record.find({ userId: req.user});
  res.json(records)
})
```

auth.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const auth = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
    if (!token)
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ msg: "No authentication token, authorization denied." });

    const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    if (!verified)
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ msg: "Token verification failed, authorization denied." });

    req.user = verified.id;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};

module.exports = auth;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been stumped on this, and it's the last thing for this app I need to do!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is best practices but I simply could not find another way to fix this problem.

I added

***window.location.reload();***

to the register.jsx and login.jsx axios request. I know this forces a reload of the document, but it's simply the only way I could get this to work, after 5 days of trying to fix this I am okay with that. If anyone knows a different way, I am all ears.